# Append a column to the end of a TSV file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a TSV (tab separated file) in which one of the headers is called session_id. I also have a map called myMap where the key is session_id and the value is session length. Now what I want is to modify the tsv file so that I add a header called "Length" to the end and also add the length values there. It means for each line I should append the session_length to the end of each line as another tab separated value.
For example, if the first line of my TSV file looks like this at first:

```
User_id   Session_id  Age    Date
23        'adasd5'    23    23/02/2017
```

And I also have:

```
myMap['adasd5']=12
```

So, the file should change to:

```
User_id   Session_id  Age    Date      Length
23        'adasd5'    23    23/02/2017   12
```

Here is what I did but it doesn't work:

```
with open('file.tsv', 'r+b') as infile:
        header=infile.next()
        h=header+'\t'+"return"+'\n'
        infile.write(h)
        for line in infile:
            line2 = line.strip().split('\t')
            if line2[1] in myMap:
                d=line+'\t'+str(myMap[line2[1]])+'\n'
            infile.write(d)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: would be willing to use pandas?

Comment: Also, in what way did what you tried not work?

Comment: @RyanStout Aw yes. I could use pandas as well if you have a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by asking a friend (@Babak).

Here is the answer:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t',names=["User_id","Session_id","Age","Date"])

df['Length']=df.session_id.apply(lambda x:myMap[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

While pandas would make this a breeze, good 'ol Python can do it just fine.  You have single quotes around your Session_id value in the tsv input file, so the output.append line of code has a .replace() method to get rid of them for the dictionary lookup.

Otherwise you're just loading in the file, specifying tab as the delimiter, skipping the header row, and ingesting the rest of the file into a list of lists.

Then you iterate over this list, appending the results of the myMap lookup to the end.  Output your new headers and write the output data to the file.

```
import csv
with open('file.tsv', newline='') as f:
    f.readline()
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = list(reader)

output = []
myMap = {
    'adasd5': 12,
}
for line in data:
    user_id, session_id, age, date = line
    output.append([user_id, session_id, age, date, myMap[session_id.replace("'", '')]])

with open('output.tsv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    headers = ['User_id', 'Session_id', 'Age', 'Date', 'Length']
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: Could you also provide your answer with pandas please?

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot first and let us know what you come up with.  Also if the first example works, why not upvote and accept it as the correct solution?

Comment: Sure. I am testing it now. Will accept the answer once it works.